# can someone complete this query for connecting sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
   <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*******";
$password = "******";
$dbname = "*****";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "EXPLAIN select created_at, user_id, power, sum(btc) Earnings\n"
    . "from btcs\n"
    . "group by user_id\n"
    . "order by user_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["user_id"]. " - Name: ". $row["user_id,"]. " " . $row["btc"] . "<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Kindly Solve this issue please..

and simple query and its work great in phpmyadmin but i dont know how to write in php page with complete dababase connection.

```
$sql = "select created_at, user_id, power, sum(btc) Earnings\n"
    . "from btcs\n"
    . "group by user_id\n"
    . "order by user_id LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're facing here?

Comment: This query works fine in phpmyadmin

Comment: but i dont know to write in phppage

Comment: @Jiten the code is **written in php**. What else do you need?

Comment: This query works fine in phpmyadmin but i dont know how to write this code in php page for complete connection

Comment: @JitenMysteriousArtist *"i dont know how to write this code in php page for complete connection"* your question shows the connection to the database and running the query **in php code** so what exactly is your problem? are you getting an error? are the results your getting different to what you are getting in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee   yes i know but its not work thats y its nt showing the data

Answer (score 0):

You should try debugging. Try this:

```
$sql = "EXPLAIN select created_at, user_id, power, sum(btc) Earnings FROM btcs GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY user_id";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$conn->error) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);   // Check if your SQL has any syntax error
}
```

Comment: ErrorException in d8d986a74fb284f902d8a97c039293c88535e68a.php line 33:
Undefined index: user_id

Comment: And what's your line no. 33?

Comment: ErrorException in d8d986a74fb284f902d8a97c039293c88535e68a.php line 25:
Undefined index: user_id (View: /home/shopturt/public_html/laravel/resources/views/pages/news.blade.php)

Comment: can you team view for solve this issue i will pay some

Comment: @JitenMysteriousArtist you do realize that means absolutely nothing when you have initially reported an error on line 33 yet you only present 31 lines of code in your question. there is no way to accurately tell if the 25th line of code in your question is the same 25th line of code that is producing your second error. for instance, line 25 of the code in your question is the `}` before the `} else {`

Comment: can i share my pc with you on team viewer

Comment: @Memor-X can i share my pc with you so you can check .

Answer (score -1):

You should write this

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "*******";
    $password = "******";
    $dbname = "*****";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


$sql = "EXPLAIN select created_at, user_id, power, sum(btc) Earnings FROM btcs GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY user_id";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$conn->error) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
}

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<br> id: ". $row["user_id"]. " - Name: ". $row["user_id,"]. " " . $row["btc"] . "<br>";
         }
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: d8d986a74fb284f902d8a97c039293c88535e68a.php line 26: